# Symfony API testing with PHPUnit: Authentication issue when making two request in same method on protected endpoint

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, phpunit

I have a login issue when performing tests on some controller for an API with Symfony 5.2.

All my endpoints are behind a firewall, and to test everything works fine, I need to login before I make a request.

I use a JWT authentication system with https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

So I have this private method on my test class :

```php
protected function logInAsUser(string $username): User
    {
        $tokenStorage = static::$client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage');
        $firewallName = 'api_area';
        $userRepository = static::$container->get(UserRepository::class);
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);
        $token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($user, $firewallName, ['ROLE_USER']);
        $tokenStorage->setToken($token);
        return $user;
    }
```

Then in my test methods, I call this method before making a request on a protected endpoint, like this :

```php
public function testSomething() {
        $this->logInAsUser('my-username');
        static::$client->request('GET', '/api/protected/endpoint/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, static::$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

And it works fine
(without calling `$this->logInAsUser('my-username);` I got a 401 response as intended)

But when I try to make two requests in the same test method, the second one fails with a 401, and the error message is : `JWT Token not found`

Example:

```php
public function testSomething() {
        $this->logInAsUser('my-username');
        static::$client->request('GET', '/api/protected/endpoint/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, static::$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());  // OK
        static::$client->request('GET', '/api/another/protected/endpoint/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, static::$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()); // FAILURE
}
```

I tried to re login before the second call, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are those two endpoints secured via the same symfony firewall? Do they have the same access_control ?

Comment: yes, I have only one firewall for now, protecting the entire api endpoints. and only one access control. And if I test the second endpoint in another method, it works fine.

Comment: try `static::$client->disableReboot()`, the "browser" reboots (i.e. clears) the kernel between requests, which includes the container and tokenstorage.

Comment: Thx for this information but it doesn't solve the issue :/

Comment: For information, I use the dama/doctrine-test-bundle as mentionned in Symfony documentation to run each tests with an unmodified database (https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#resetting-the-database-automatically-before-each-test). I don't know if it could have some influence on this issue

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 5.1 the Client used in WebTestcases provides a built-in method to mock a logged in user:

`public function loginUser($user, string $firewallContext = 'main'): self`

You should try using that one instead of doing it yourself.

```
public function testSomething() 
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    
    $testUser = $userRepository->findOneByUsername('my-username');
    $client->loginUser($testUser);

    $client->request('GET', '/api/protected/endpoint/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());  // OK
    
    $client->request('GET', '/api/another/protected/endpoint/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()); // FAILURE
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work with my authentication system :/